# JavaScript In Protractor

Tags: javascript, iframe, protractor

[Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Eclp.png)I have to automate click on dropdown inside an iframe using protractor.

Iframe:

```
<iframe src="swagger-ui/index.html" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" 
        width="100%" height="900" scrolling="auto" target="_top" class="ng-scope">
</iframe>
```

Dropdown:

```
<select id="select_baseUrl" name="select_baseUrl">
  <option value="1">default (1)</option>
  <option value="2">eventui (2)</option>
  <option value="3">eventservice (3)</option>
</select>
```

I tried

```
var eeel = browser.executeScript("document.getElementByTagName('iframe')
                  .contentWindow.document.getElementById('select_baseUrl').click();");

browser.wait(eeel,200000);
console.log("Lv2");
```

But not working.

Comment: I solved the issue.  ................................        browser.driver.switchTo().frame(0).then(function(){
   console.log('now inside fn1 SRC1');
   browser.driver.sleep(5000);
browser.driver.findElement(by.id('select_baseUrl')).click();
   console.log('Now fn2 SRC1');
   browser.driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
  });

Comment: Could you accept my answer since it solved your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are abusing the `executeScript()` function which is not needed in this case at all. Protractor (and the underlying Webdriver.js) allows you to switch Iframes using:

`browser.driver.switchTo().frame(0);`

in most cases using `0` should return the first iframe visible on the page, but if there are more you have to find the appropriate index number.

Once you have switched you can find elements as you normally would. But once you are done you must switch back to the default window using `browser.driver.switchTo().defaultContent();`

Comment: I am new to this, sorry . I tried this already , says defaultContent() is not a function. If i remove that and try, i get " Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page:"

Comment: You'll need to post more of your code to see what the problem might be.

Comment: Hope this is enough,                                                 browser.driver.switchTo().frame(0);
  element(by.xpath("//select[@='select_baseUrl']")).click();
  browser.driver.switchTo.defaultContent();                                  Thank you

Comment: Unfortunately that's not enough to see what's going on. You should update your question with your attempt to use the `switchTo()` method and post the exact error that appears when you do that. Also showing us more of your test file would be helpful.

Comment: I added a snapshot , Thank you .

Comment: Is there any other way like using javaScriptexecutor or something like that ?